# Add and delete entities in symfony form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Doctrine entity Document, that has a bidirectional oneToMany relation to an entity File. So one Document can have many File entities.

Now I want to make a symfony form, where I can add and delete files from the document. I set up a FileType that is included in the DocumentType via CollectionType:

```
//DocumentType.php
$builder->add('files', Type\CollectionType::class, ['entry_type' => FileType::class])

//FileType.php
$builder->add('id', Type\HiddenType::class);
```

That way I get hidden fields with the file-ids. I now wanted to disable fields via JS if a File should be removed from Document. But I cant send the form, because I get the error:

```
Could not determine access type for property "id".
```

Its just because I want to use the id of Field. Of course, I could use src or any other column of File to identify the right Entity for deleting.

But I hope, there is an overall better way do deal with this problem in symfony?

Here my Entity mappings:

```
AppBundle\Entity\File:
    type: entity
    table: files
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\FileRepository
    manyToOne:
        document:
            targetEntity: Document
            inversedBy: files
            joinColumn:
                onDelete: CASCADE
```

---

```
AppBundle\Entity\Document:
    type: entity
    table: documents
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\DocumentRepository
    oneToMany:
        files:
            targetEntity: File
            mappedBy: document
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not Symfony problem, your `File` entity does not has any method to set the value of `id` property. The error cause when Symfony's form data mapper trying to map the submitted ids to your `File` entities using `PropertyAccessor`.

One more thing, if you want to allow your collection add/remove entries, the option `allow_add`/`allow_delete` must be `true`. You do not needs to add any identify fields to your `FileType`, Symfony form handle it by indexing, I guess..

```
// DocumentType.php
$builder->add('files', Type\CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => FileType::class,
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true
]);

// FileType.php
// Add fields you want to show up to end-user to edit.
$builder
    ->add('name', Type\TextType::class)
    ->add('description', Type\TextareaType::class)
;
```

Comment: thanks, but how can I delete an entity then? When I don't add any fields to change its value, how can I mark that an entity should be deletet?

Comment: yes, you should add some fields like my example abow to presents your entry. You just delete it using javascript and Symfony form will delete that entry for you. Have a look at this documentation, it very detailed about Symfony form collection: [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)

Comment: I just tried, added one field, disabled it via JS, checked that it was not in the POST Data, but symfony didnt delete it. ok I will check your doc page again.

Comment: Are you sure the `allow_delete` option is `true`? Can you post your `Document` and `File` entities, so I can view how you remove your references.

Comment: posted them in question, maybe its a problem because Document is not the owning side? I just checked, the `removeFile()` method of Document is not called by the form submit

Comment: No, I needs to view your entity in php file, not mapping files.

Comment: yes it looks like, the problem is that Document is on the inversed side, you can read that in the very last part of your link https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html I will try to solve it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140004/discussion-between-pig-ball-and-asara).

Comment: that was the problem, because Document is not the owning side, you need to remove the files manually (its described in the docu, see above). Anyway, your answer was correct to my question, but maybe you want to add that problem and the solution to your post.